# What would Maxwell's Equations be if we had magnetic charges and magnetic currents?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, maxwell-equations, magnetic-monopoles, duality

Mind you, we still have electric charge and electric currents. But, what would [Maxwell's equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations) look like if we had to take magnetic charges and magnetic currents into consideration? Would there be any sign changes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By analogy (between $\mathbf{E}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ as they are pretty much equivalent) then the divergeance of $\mathbf{B}$ field wouldn't be 0 anymore, instead: $$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{B}= \frac{\rho_{\rm magnetic}}{\mu_0} $$
With $\rho_{\rm magnetic}$ the magnetic charge density, and $\mu_0$ the permeability in vacuum, to interpret it, the divergence of the magnetic field at a point in space is equal to the magnetic charge density divided by the permeability of space.

As for the curl equations, with magnetic charges, curl of $\mathbf{E}$ should also give a non-zero density current of magnetic charges, i.e.: $$\nabla \times\mathbf{E}= -\mu_0 \mu \frac{\partial \mathbf{H}}{\partial t} + \sigma_m \mathbf{B} $$

Where $\sigma_m$ would then be the magnetic conductivity.

Answer (score 3):

A slight correction to the answer posted above:

Gauss' Law for Magnetic field will now take the form:

$$
\nabla \cdot \vec{B}=\mu_0 \rho_m\\
$$
i.e.
$$\bigcirc \!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! \iint \vec{B}\cdot\text{d}\vec{A}=\mu_0 \iiint \rho_m \text{d}V
$$

The expression for the curl of the electric field becomes:
$$
\nabla\times\vec{E}=-\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}-\vec{J}_m\\
i.e. \oint \vec{E}\cdot\text{d}\vec{l}=-\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\bigg(\iint\vec{B}\cdot\text{d}\vec{A}\bigg)-\mu_0 I_m
$$

The remaining two equations stay the same.

($\rho_m$=magnetic charge density, $\vec{J}_m$=Magnetic current, $I_m$=magnetic current)