# Electric Field lines that close on themselves

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields

What causes an electric field line to close on itself as opposed to other cases?

Comment: [$\vec \nabla \cdot \vec E = 0$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_line#Divergence_and_curl)

Comment: Nothing. An electric "field line" is a line drawn by people on paper to visualize a vector field.

Answer (score 4):

You are talking about a "divergence-free" field, otherwise known as a [solenoidal field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoidal_vector_field). In such cases, $\nabla \cdot \vec{E}=0$ and electric field lines have no beginning and no end.

From Maxwell's equations we see that $\nabla \cdot \vec{E}=0$ when the charge density is zero. So, for instance, electric field lines cannot begin or end in a vacuum or in an entirely neutral medium.

Magnetic fields are always divergence-free, because unlike electric fields, there are (probably) no monopoles that act as sources of B-field.

Divergence-free E-fields can be produced without free charges according to the Maxwell-Faraday law.
$$ \nabla \times \vec{E} = -\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}$$

Answer (score -1):

Magnetic monopole (if they existed) currents and time-dependent magnetic inductions (from $\nabla\times\mathbf E = -\frac{\partial\mathbf B}{\partial t} + \mathbf J_m$).

Comment: Magnetic monopoles would be the opposite case - magnetic fields that have a nonzero divergence and thus have field lines that do not form closed loops. All magnetic fields, as described by Maxwell's equations, have field lines that "close on themselves."

Comment: my bad, i just confused monopoles with monopole current, as correctly indicated by the equation I wrote.

Comment: A related discussion can be found [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/129401/what-would-maxwells-equations-be-if-we-had-magnetic-charges-and-magnetic-curren/129405#129405).