How would a magnetic monopole behave around a live wire?
Given a direction of current in a wire, and the magnetic field perpendicular to the wire forms with say "north" pointing clockwise (right-hand-rule convention). If we placed a small monopole object corresponding to "south" in the field around the wire, would it form a clockwise helix around the wire since it's only attracted to the "north" of the field, and continuously loop around the wire until other forces take it off the path?

You are free to solve Maxwell's equations in the presence of a magnetic charge density, if you so choose. You just write $\vec \nabla \cdot \vec B = 4\pi \rho_M$ instead of $\vec \nabla \cdot \vec B = 0$. (See Schwinger's textbook on Electrodynamics for a treatment that carries around the magnetic charge density for no reason.)

Hi hft, for my clarity, the [4πρM] instead of 0 allows us specifically to look at a monopole which is simply a magnetic charge, am I following correctly?

It allows you to look at any magnetic charge distribution. The $4\pi$ is just because I am used to Gaussian units: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_units#Maxwell's_equations

Here is a similar question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/129401/what-would-maxwells-equations-be-if-we-had-magnetic-charges-and-magnetic-curren

That’s a very good question. Thanks for your help. Follow-up to the first question. I have ordered the QED book per your reference as this is an area of physics that never ceases to amaze, and the book is a great compilation.

Hint: you might solve the problem in plane polar coordinates, since your monopole will never leave the plane perpendicular to the current-carrying wire. The magnetic field induced by the wire will vary as b/r, so the equations of motion will be
$$
\ddot{\vec r}=\hat{r} (\ddot r -r\dot\theta^2)+ \hat\theta (r\ddot\theta+2\dot r \dot \theta)= \hat \theta {b\over r}
$$
so that
$$
\ddot r = r\dot\theta ^2, ~~~~ r\ddot\theta+2\dot r \dot \theta={b\over r}~~. 
$$
You may solve these and perhaps eliminate t from them, so as to express your parametric spiral, $r(\theta)$ .

Hi Cosmas, thank you for response. If I'm following you, [r¨=rθ˙2] is the change in radial distance across time, and [rθ¨+2r˙θ˙=b/r] is the change in angle? I was only asking if the monopole in such a situation would behave by circling the wire, never mind describing its path! But your response is a far more detailed and higher level response than I anticipated and i appreciate it!

Yes, the second equation monitors the change in the polar angle. It determines the spiral, whose precise form I have not recognized, myself.
